# How to calculate the intersection of two arcs given by endpoints and point-on-the-arc?

Tags: python, intersection

2 arcs setted with 3 points: 2 bounds and point in arc (to understand which side of circle between points is arc)
so i need to write arc intersection code on python

```
def get_arc_sortbased(data, break_angle):
  points = data.loc[:,'x':]
  angles = points.apply(convert_to_angle,axis=1)
  points['angles'] = angles
  modes = get_mode_angle(points.loc[:,'angles'],radius=2).tolist()
  print('MODES')
  print(modes)
  points = points.sort_values(by=['angles'])
  point_lst = points['angles'].tolist()
  arcs = []
  for mode in modes:
    cent = point_lst[bs.bisect_right(point_lst, mode)]
    end_1 = find_arc_end(point_lst, mode, break_angle)
    end_2 = find_arc_end(point_lst, mode, break_angle, direction='clockwise', endPoint=end_1)
    arcs.append([end_1, cent, end_2])
  return arcs
```

Comment: The title should reflect more the problem you're facing, not what you're doing ;)

Comment: Please add example input and desired output

Comment: for example you have 2 arcs:
1) (0,-1), (1,0) and (0,1)
2) (1, 0), (0.6, 0.8) and (0, 1)
so the intersection will be the second arc itself in this case and the example of the answers is ((1, 0), (0.6, 0.8), (0, 1))

Comment: Do you also want the intersection points in case there are 1 or 2? (Please answer by editing the question, not here in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), Python's symbolic math library. First two circles are constructed, and their intersection is calculated. The intersection can either be a full circle (when both circles are the same), two points, one point (tangential circles) or empty.

The basic idea is that when an intersection point is at the same side of the line defined by the arc bounds, as the third point, then the intersection point belongs to the arc.

The case when the intersection is the complete circle, is not addressed in the code. Then, there are three possibilities: the arcs don't overlap, they overlap in exactly one point (a common end point), or they overlap as an arc. An overlapping arc would be bounded by 2 of the 4 end points. Possibly a new "third" point has to be sought when the existing "third" points wouldn't belong to the overlap. Note that the case of overlapping arcs would be very tricky with precision errors in the case of float-valued coordinates.

```py
from sympy.geometry import Point, Circle, Line
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

def signed_distance(line, pnt):
    # find the signed distance between a line and a point by substituting the point into the line equation
    # note that this distance is not yet normalized, as we are only interested in the sign
    assert isinstance(line, Line) and isinstance(pnt, Point)
    eq = parse_expr(str(line.equation()), local_dict={'x':pnt.x, 'y':pnt.y})
    return eq.simplify()

def are_at_same_side(line, pnt1, pnt2):
    return signed_distance(line, pnt1) * signed_distance(line, pnt2) >= 0

p1 = Point(1, 4) # suppose the arc segment is defined by p1 and p2 as endpoints, and containing p3
p2 = Point(3, 2)
p3 = Point(1, 2)
q1 = Point(2, 3)
q2 = Point(4, 1)
q3 = Point(2, 1)
cp = Circle(p1, p2, p3)  # the circle defined by the three points
cq = Circle(q1, q2, q3)
inters = cp.intersection(cq) # intersection between the 2 circles
if isinstance(inters, Circle):
    pass # TODO: the two arcs overlap
elif len(inters) == 2:
    i1, i2 = inters
elif len(inters) == 1:
    i1 = inters[0]

# line connecting the two end points; if the third point and an intersection point lie
# on the same side of the line, then the intersection point is on the arc
lp = Line(p1, p2)
lq = Line(q1, q2)

if isinstance(inters, Circle):
    solutions = [] # TODO: the two arcs overlap
else:
    solutions = [(i1.evalf().x, i1.evalf().y) for i1 in inters
                 if i1 is not None and are_at_same_side(lp, p3, i1) and are_at_same_side(lq, q3, i1)]
print(solutions)
```